# Patterns for building reusable controls which can work according to the context in which it's running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, design-patterns

Please refer to the image.

The three big black coloured rectangles are my 3 different forms. They belong to 3 different contexts in my application.
The red coloured box is control placed on all 3 forms.
However, the visibility (& permissible values, validation rules etc) of the red box depends on some other controls' visibility and/or the value user is entering on the form it's put on. E.g. In first form, visibility would change according to the green controls' visibility. On the other form, allowed value in the red box would be dependent on the value selected in the blue list control and so on.

How should I handle the values/state/validation  of the red control?

One option is to have a logic embedded in each form. But that would lead to duplication of code everywhere.

Is state pattern an option? If yes, then the red control's server side logic would have to handle all contexts? And how would that piece of logic know when values in the green or blue controls are changed?

**I want to have a reusable red text box which would behave in the desired way in every context it's being used.**

Which pattern should I use in such cases? If I call server side logic on change of every control (gree, blue etc) on the forms just to calculate visibility/values of the red box, is that a good option considering performance?

I have a ASP.NET application.

(Red control is illustrative. This could be more complex control or set of controls.)[image]

Comment: Please mention the reason why you are downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is to use one of existing frameworks which support this design.
For example

- Angular 2/4
- Backbone
- Vue

Is many many other but with this I have experience and works perfect for me.